# Does Azure App Services have a unique id of some kind that will travel with the code between slots

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In the old Cloud Service model there was a property called **DeploymentId** that was unique and traveled with the code base as it was swapped between Production and Staging slots.

In the App Service architecture (Functions, etc...) there is also a **deploymentId** property as well but it appears to not travel with the code as it swaps slots.  In non-prod slots it presents as **[ServiceName]__abcd** where abcd looks to be a hexidecimal string. In prod slots it presents as **[ServiceName]** only.  This means that the deploymentId mutates depending upon where it lives.

The crux of the matter is that I need to be able to determine where a given deployment lives using ONLY azure native values. It does not appear that there is a unique identifier that lives with the deployed code.

Am I wrong?  please tell me I'm wrong and that there is a unique value that will travel.

Using Azure REST API to query.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID` http header, it should be travelling with the code. i.e. the value it you get for it in the Production slot will toggle between two value each time you swap.

You can use the Environment tab in Kudu to easily look at it on both slots, before and after swap.

Comment: yah, thats the same value that is in the rest service return and matches `deploymentId`.  Its the one that mutates depending upon whether it lives in the Production slot or a non-Production slot.  So.. It doesn't travel with the code (at least in a consistent way)  This is the one I'm referring to in my question.

Comment: That should not be the case. As a test, does it make a difference if you create a DUMMY app setting in the Portal and mark it as a slot setting? Then try testing again.

Comment: That header is not guaranteed to be on an app service.  I have app services I am hitting currently and the header isn't present.  Must be something that is dependent on your code strategy.  I can say definitively that the `deploymentId` value WILL mutate depending upon the slot its in.  I am using Azure REST API to query my information FYI.  didn't add that to the original question, my mistake, I'll update.

Comment: As an alternative, you could just create a DEPLOYMENT_ID App Setting in each slot (**not** marked a slot setting!). Set it to different value in each slot, and the value will definitely travel with the code as you swap.

Comment: won't be valid in my scenario.  I am limited to values provided by Azure REST API that are standard across any app service.